# Repeat values in a column n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe

```
 Code 
   1
   3
   4
   5
```

I want to repeat each code value 5 times so that output is:

```
 Code 
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   3
   3
   3
   3
   3
   4
   4
   4
   4
   4
   5
   5
   5
   5
   5
```

np.repeat does not seem to work on dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the index:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(5)]
```